# what is the verb used when getting rid of evil spirits

Tags: word-choice

What is the verb that means "to get rid of evil spirits"

Not ghost-busting. Something more serious, less comedic.

Comment: *[Exorcise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/exorcise)* in the absence of other context.

Comment: @dhdes Just found a couple hits of "de-evil" on Google Books...https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DIZEXVhLF30C&pg=PA23&dq=%22de-eviled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIyt6D4MDqyAIVgm4aCh2hrAvy#v=onepage&q=%22de-eviled%22&f=false; https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bHUI0jsPlXEC&pg=RA1-PA193&dq=%22de-eviling%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIiPSe8MDqyAIVibQaCh14OQ4f#v=onepage&q=%22de-eviling%22&f=false;

Answer (score 17):

**Exorcise** is the formal, technical term for driving out evil spirits, deriving from *exorcism*, an official ritual of the Catholic church.

> **exorcise:**
>   1.to seek to expel (an evil spirit) by adjuration or religious or solemn ceremonies.
>   2.to free (a person, place, etc.) of evil spirits or malignant influences.
>   -- http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exorcise

As an alternative, **banish** is a good general term meaning to drive out.

> **banish**
>   1. to expel from or relegate to a country or place by authoritative decree; condemn to exile:
>   2. to compel to depart; send, drive, or put away:
>   --http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banish?s=t

Answer (score 6):

To **exorcise** is the word you're looking for (cross-posted with @Chris Sunami.)

> 1. To expel (an evil spirit) by or as if by incantation, command, or prayer.
> 2. To free from evil spirits or malign influences.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=exorcise))

In addition, phrasal verbs like **[cast out](http://www.greatbiblestudy.com/casting_out_demons.php)** or **drive out** could work too, depending on the context:

> and to have authority to **drive out** demons.

(http://biblehub.com/mark/3-15.htm, the NIV translation)

Comment: It's always a bit of a race when there's an obvious answer :)

Comment: Yeah, the cookie tends to crumble a certain way, gotta roll with it :)

Answer (score 4):

**Cast out** is often used in modern biblical translations:

> That evening they brought to him many who were oppressed by demons, and he **cast out** the spirits with a word and healed all who were sick. ([Matthew 8:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Matthew%208:16); quoted translation is ESV)

Out of the 53 translations of this verse included in that link, a strong plurality (26) use *cast out*.

As defined by [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast%20out), the phrase indicates *driving out*, or *expelling*.

Comment: Yeah, "cast out" was what I thought of initially. Some translations use "drive out" instead, like the NIV in Mark 3:15.

Answer (score 2):

I don't disagree that ***exorcise*** is a more *specific* verb for OP's context, but I would just point out these usage figures from Google Books...

> *to **exorcise** the ghost* [- about 4,150 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20exorcise%20the%20ghost%22)
>    *to **lay** the ghost* [- about 9,230 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to%20lay%20the%20ghost%22)

That's sense 23 in [thefreedictionary...](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lay)

> ***lay*** *- to quiet or make vanish: **to lay a ghost**.*

Comment: ... Why is a ghost like a carpet? ?

Comment: @Edwin: Is a boxer like a carpet just because his opponent [laid him out with a left hook?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22laid+him+out+with+a+left+hook%22) (Maybe because the victor *walked all over him!* :)

Comment: Also the film "High Spirits", where Steve Guttenberg does lay a ghost...

Comment: I've never heard this usage, at least not independent of the larger phrase "lay... to rest."  Is it exclusively British English?

Comment: @Chris: Comparing the [US/UK corpuses in Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+lay+the+ghost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20lay%20the%20ghost%3B%2Cc0) does suggest it's *somewhat* more common in BrE, but it's not a huge difference. Interestingly, if I exclude ***...to rest*** in [my search terms](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+lay+the+ghost%22+-%22ghost+to+rest%22), Google Books only reduces its guesstimate by 40 (to 9190). I suspect it's probably not a very accurate guess.

Comment: It looks like it's chiefly an older usage --perhaps because of the common use of "lay" as a sexual euphemism?

Comment: @Chris: It only sounds a bit "old, dated" to me when used *literally* (in my universe, actual ghosts and evil spirits are just relics of a more primitive past). I don't see figurative usages such as [*lay that idea to rest*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lay+that+idea+to+rest%22) as particularly old-fashioned.

Comment: But what if you try that on "demon"?  (It ain't even close.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: Aw, c'mon! *Ghosts* and *evil spirits* might be a bit Victorian, but *demons* are positively medieval!

Answer (score 1):

'Exorcize' would be the correct term.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers at StackExchange are expected to be definitive; your contribution would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other fine answers posted, I've heard the phrase "dispel evil spirits".

Comment: This answer would be stronger if you linked to a reference work, like a dictionary, showing how it is defined and used.

Answer (score 1):

***Exorcise*** is probably the right answer, but you may also consider ***purify*** depending on the context.

For example, a Catholic priest uses a *purificator* to *purify* his fingers and the chalice from evil before blessing and handling the Eucharist.  The priest does not *exorcise* his fingers or the chalice, but he is still getting rid of evil. 
If the evil described is not a specific evil spirit(s), but evil itself, you'd want to use *purify*.

Answer (score 1):

[**purge**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=purged+of+evil&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpurged%20of%20evil%3B%2Cc0)

> : to rid (someone or something) of something unwanted [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/purge)
>
> *He knew if they could just obey Him now, all of creation could be
>   purged of the Evil One and the Lord would rule and reign in the earth
>   with mankind forever. The day of the great test came and God watched
>   as Satan approached Eve.* [When Will These Things Be: The Next Journey](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8qXlmJB7YIsC&pg=PA2&dq=%22purged+of+the+evil%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwA2oVChMIkcL2md7qyAIVBl4UCh0abgUk#v=onepage&q=%22purged%20of%20the%20evil%22&f=false)
>
> *When he had asked his grandmother why this very sick woman had not
>   been taken to a physician, she had answered that no doctor could do
>   what they had done for her: purge her body of the evil spirit that
>   possessed it.* [In the Shadow of the Sphinx](https://books.google.fr/books?id=iiBO6QZCgc4C&pg=PT227&dq=%22of+the+evil+spirit%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBzigAWoVChMI6MjRm-XqyAIVCcAUCh34GQQ0#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20evil%20spirit%22&f=false)

**exsufflate**

> (*Eccles.*) to  exorcise or renounce by blowing [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, published 1913](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Exsufflate)
>
> **THE EXSUFFLATION**
>
> The priest breathes three times on the child in the
>   form of a cross, saying: Go out of him...you unclean spirit and give
>   place to the Holy Spirit, the Paraclete.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insufflation)
>
> *His rejoinder to it here is to point to the other parts of the same ritual, and to ask why, then, infants are exorcised and exsufflated in
>   baptism. For, it cannot be doubted that this is done fictitiously, if
>   the Devil does not rule over them ; but if he rules over them, and
>   they are therefore not falsely exorcised and exsufflated, why does
>   that prince of sinners rule over them except because of sin?* [Saint
>   Augustine's Anti-Pelagian Writings (Extended Annotated
>   Edition)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=W6GyVbwzbngC&pg=PT109&dq=%22sinners+rule+over+them+except+because+of+%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIiva0v_HqyAIVilUaCh0z-QE5#v=onepage&q=%22sinners%20rule%20over%20them%20except%20because%20of%20%22&f=false)*

**dispossess**

> : to banish [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dispossess)
>
> *Such persons are even more to be pitied than the dumb man was, whom
>   our Saviour dispossessed of the evil spirit.* [Expository discourses on the Gospels for every Sunday in the year ..., Volume 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Eh0HAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA327&lpg=PA327&dq=%22dispossessed+of+the+evil+spirit%22&source=bl&ots=wIgFO-pAaB&sig=FpOAtLeDNzS00HFVECsJa47X2eQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwjztPrk6urIAhVGXBoKHUxpCto#v=onepage&q=%22dispossessed%20of%20the%20evil%20spirit%22&f=false)

[**expulse**](http://findwords.info/term/expulse)

> : to expel [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expulse)
>
> : a synonym of expel; sometimes expressing more strongly the notion of
>   violence [OED](http://findwords.info/term/expulse)
>
> Luke 10:17 *The seventy two disciples returned to the Lord telling him
>   how they had expulsed evil spirits in his name.* [The Work of God](http://www.theworkofgod.org/Library/Exorcism/exorcsm4.htm)

Answer (score 0):

One more answer: **Ward off spells** may fit.

> For example: The wizzard warded off the spell casted by the witch.

Answer (score -1):

The word **adjure** does not specifically mean the warding off or banishing of spirits but often arises in that context. The definition is [to urge or command (someone) to do something](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjure), and it is used in the context of exorcism at times, most famously perhaps in this passage from the King James Bible (Acts 19:13),

> Then certain of the vagabond Jews, exorcists, took upon them to call over them which had evil spirits the name of the Lord Jesus, saying, We adjure you by Jesus whom Paul preacheth.

Basically, "In the name of Jesus, I *command* you to get lost."

Comment: *Adjure* by itself has nothing to do with evil spirits.

Comment: Indeed, I said that explicitly, but it still does have this use. One also sees it a lot in fictional portrayals of exorcism. I think it's a relevant response.

Comment: "I adjure you to haunt this place and make a right nuisance of yourself" would be just as correct a use of *adjure* though.